`java.lang.IllegalStateException`: LST contains missing or invalid type information in OpenRewrite Custom Java Recipe
I'm working on a migration recipe using OpenRewrite to transform Play Framework controller into Spring Boot REST controller.Currently, I have not written any LST modification code in visitor and seeing this error.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LST contains missing or invalid type information
MethodInvocation->Return->Block->MethodDeclaration->Block->ClassDeclaration->CompilationUnit
/*~~(MethodInvocation type is missing or malformed)~~>*/ok("Hello, World!")

    at org.openrewrite.java.Assertions.assertValidTypes(Assertions.java:87)
    at org.openrewrite.java.Assertions.validateTypes(Assertions.java:57)
    at org.openrewrite.test.RewriteTest.rewriteRun(RewriteTest.java:305)
    at org.openrewrite.test.RewriteTest.rewriteRun(RewriteTest.java:133)
    at org.openrewrite.test.RewriteTest.rewriteRun(RewriteTest.java:128)
    at com.yourorg.NewPlayToSpringControllersRecipeTest.migratePlayControllerAndMethodToSpringRestController(NewPlayToSpringControllersRecipeTest.java:23)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)

Here is the test method:
package com.yourorg;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.openrewrite.InMemoryExecutionContext;
import org.openrewrite.java.Assertions;
import org.openrewrite.java.JavaParser;
import org.openrewrite.test.RecipeSpec;
import org.openrewrite.test.RewriteTest;

public class NewPlayToSpringControllersRecipeTest implements RewriteTest {


    @Override
    public void defaults(RecipeSpec spec) {
        spec.recipe(new NewPlayToSpringControllersRecipe())
          .parser(JavaParser.fromJavaVersion().classpathFromResources(new InMemoryExecutionContext(),
            "jackson-databind", "jackson-core", "jackson-annotations",
            "spring-web-6.1.+", "play_2.11-2.7.+"));
    }

    @Test
    void migratePlayControllerAndMethodToSpringRestController() {
        rewriteRun(
          Assertions.java(
            """
              package com.example;

              import play.mvc.Controller;
              import play.mvc.Result;                            

              public class MyController extends Controller {
                  
                  public Result sayHello() {
                      return ok("Hello, World!");
                  }
              }
              """
          )
        );
    }
}

And here is the code for the getVisitor method:
package com.yourorg;

import org.openrewrite.ExecutionContext;
import org.openrewrite.Recipe;
import org.openrewrite.TreeVisitor;
import org.openrewrite.java.*;
import org.openrewrite.java.tree.J;

public class NewPlayToSpringControllersRecipe extends Recipe {

    @Override
    public String getDisplayName() {
        return "Migrate play framework controllers to spring boot REST controllers";
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return "Transforms Play Framework controllers to Spring Boot REST controllers by removing the Play-specific superclass " +
                "and adding the @RestController annotation.";
    }


    @Override
    public TreeVisitor<?, ExecutionContext> getVisitor() {
        return new JavaIsoVisitor<ExecutionContext>() {
            @Override
            public J.ClassDeclaration visitClassDeclaration(J.ClassDeclaration cd, ExecutionContext executionContext) {
                System.out.println("visitClassDeclaration\n" + TreeVisitingPrinter.printTree(getCursor()));
                return super.visitClassDeclaration(cd, executionContext);
            }
        };
    }
}


Was Expecting test to pass!!

Could it be your text blocks are missing an import static play.mvc.Results.ok; ? I'm not familiar with Play, so just going by what you've explained above.

Hi Tim, Static import is not necessary. There is no compilation issue.

The Controller of play framework extends Results class.

But aren't you removing that extemds Controller from your HomeController? After that were would that ok come from?

If I remove the code to change extends or rather simply return super.visitClassDeclaration(classDecl, executionContext) from visitClassDeclaration() I am getting same error. Somehow, it is not able to create the LST.

Have you tried copying that second text block to a new file as a quick check? I think you'll find a compilation error there too because ok is not defined.

Yes, in the second text block of assertion i get compilation error. So, I am modified as below. But, still getting the same error  `
package com.example;
public class MyController {
              public String sayHello() {
                      return "Hello, World!";
              }

}`

Can you edit your question to show the new before, after, and exception? Because there can't be a missing type on ok if that's not in there

Your recipe isn't yet removing that ok right?

Hi, I have updated the question. I have removed all LST modification logic from visitor, but i am still getting same error. Somehow its not able to find ok() method.

I'm really thinking that import static play.mvc.Results.ok; is going to help you here, as the method is static, not part of methods implicitly available from the interface without an import.

There is a solution on official page: https://docs.openrewrite.org/reference/faq#im-seeing-lst-contains-missing-or-invalid-type-information-in-my-recipe-unit-tests-how-to-resolve
